# how to use ui-router inside a function with static menu without creating default back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI router with Ionic. I want to redirect page from one to another within a function.

I have default menu in all pages.

[image]

I tried used `$state.go`. but `$state.go` is changing the whole url and creating a back button.

[image]

I want my menu still be there in my page.

Here is my code:
**controller.js:**

```
$scope.changeState = function () {
    $state.go('app.registration');
  };
```

**app.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'signinController'
        }
      }
    }) 
    .state('app.registration', {
      url: '/registration',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/registration.html',
          controller: 'signupController'
        }
      }
    })
```

})

Finally what i want is, I want to redirect the page inside a function call, and my menu should be there. i dont want default back button.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks,
Priya.

Comment: what is the state config for /dashboard?

Comment: now i am roughly using app.registration.

Comment: add in your css for hide default back button `.back-button{display:none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For menu to be there, your Dashboard has to be a child of Main view. `app.login` means `login` is a child view of app.
2. Back button appears because your login view is still in history. You have to clear history before  view change on successful login. [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) will help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can i do that? Can you please guide me?

Comment: For nested states, you should go through this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views
For clearing history use $ionicHistory.clearHistory();